# Show/Hide UIButton in another controller

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, appdelegate

I have a button in my ViewController.swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var exampleButton: UIButton!
```

I would like to show/hide that button from the AppDelegate, when something specific happens (i.e. the app enter background etc.).
How can i do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One Approach can be 
 - You can use Notifications for this

Add **Observer** in your view controller where button needs to be hidden

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "hideButton",
    name: @"HIDE_BUTTON_NOTIFICATION",
    object: nil)



func hideButton() -> Void {
  // Hide your button here
  // Remember to hide on main thread
}
```

From wherever you want **to hide the button** (like from AppDelegate), you can post this notification

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(@"HIDE_BUTTON_NOTIFICATION", object: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, sounds like an amazing way to do what I need!!

Comment: My only comment on this is that some remote object shouldn't be "controlling" the UI of some other view. Later on you might have two views that do different things based on some condition. Post the condition (state) that is driving the view controller(s) - perhaps "LoggedIn" or "NotLoggedIn", then take the appropriate action when needed. To be so specific about a single UI object in a notification is a "code smell" and will just cause you (or others) problems later on.

Comment: Thanks David. I understand and I will try to group the actions together in one place/function to avoid different behaviours..! thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than let another object directly manipulate it, use a notification to indicate a state change. The state dictates whether the button appears or not.

Make sure in your notification listener that you only touch the button on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to use the notifications!

Answer (score 1):

Notification is a great idea, but what if your ViewController is not your initial ViewController, or hasn't been initialized yet? It will not be able to catch this notification. Possible solution (maybe not elegant) in extension to other answers is to provide a flag. Your ViewController will be checking it, e.g. in `viewDidLoad()`. Your flag could be stored in a singleton object which will be catching notification from AppDelegate.

To sum up, you should add notification observer in your ViewController, to catch event from AppDelegate. (like in other answers)

Create singleton class to store appropriate information.
Check condition in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if YOUR_SINGLETON.YOUR_FLAG == true {
     showButton()
} else {
     hideButton()
}
```

Don't forget to add notification observer also in your singleton class.

Comment: absolutely needed! I agree with your point, good observation. Thank you very much :-)